# Break from loop in Silverstripe Template

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe

Simply put, is it in anyway possible to `break` out of a loop within a template file (.ss)

eg.

You have an ArrayList which you want to loop over until you find the key you need. In this scenario, I need to track down `MyRequestVar` and escape the loop immediately afterwards.

```
<% loop $RequestVars %>
    <% if $Key == "MyRequestVar" %>
        MyRequestVar is set to $Value
        <% break_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Of course I can just let it continue to iterate the ArrayList and it will work as intended but my OCD is kicking in regarding perf++

Comment: It would be better to do this in your PHP code.

Comment: I don't not agree with you :)

Comment: <% loop $RequestVars.filter(Key, "MyRequestVar") %> an if you need with a Modifier like :GreaterThanFilter

Comment: Not breaking loop per-say, but better than it; Throw that up as an answer @munomono for a tick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to break from the loop in your provided context

However you can filter the ArrayList from within the template like so:

```
<% loop $RequestVars.filter(Key, "MyRequestVar") %>
```

You can also use [SearchFilter Modifiers](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/)

Comment: just a note aside: Since you can use filter/sort/limit in template and $list("Page") to get DataObjects you rarely need to write php-getters. may one say this is bad practice but me I like it :)

Comment: Well, `$LatestNews` is more declarative than `$List('News').sort(...).limit(5)`, but that's mostly a matter of preference